Getting 'too many arguments' error when calling a contract function through a forwarder contract using Openzeppelin's defender in Ethereum
I'm trying to interact with a smart contract function through a forwarder in Ethereum using Openzeppelin's defender relayer, but I'm encountering an error message that says:
too many arguments: passed to contract (count=2, expectedCount=1, code=UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)

Here's the scenario:
I have a smart contract deployed on the Ethereum network.
I'm using a forwarder contract (ERC2771Forwarder) to relay transactions to the target contract.
When I try to execute a function call on the target contract through the action of Openzeppelin defender, I'm passing the necessary parameters, but I'm getting the mentioned error message.
This is my Smart contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Context.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Forwarder.sol";

contract MetaSum is ERC2771Context {
    uint public sum;

    constructor(
        ERC2771Forwarder forwarder // Initialize trusted forwarder
    ) ERC2771Context(address(forwarder)) {}

    function add(uint _a) public {
        sum = _a;
    }
}

This is my main.js file which is used in frontend:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import config from "./config/config";
import axios from "axios";
import { signMetaTxRequest } from "./eth/signer";
import { createInstance } from "./eth/forwarder";
require("dotenv").config();

const Main = () => {
  const { contract_Address, contract_ABI } = config;
  const [sumContract, setSumContract] = useState();
  const [signer, setSigner] = useState();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState();
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState();

  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState("");
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState("");
  const [sum, setSum] = useState("");

  // Handler for connecting wallet
  const connectWalletHandler = async () => {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    // Web3Modal is a library that simplifies the process of connecting to a user's Ethereum wallet, like MetaMask.
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(connection);
    if (provider) {
      const getnetwork = await provider.getNetwork();
      const sepoliaChainId = 11155111;

      if (getnetwork.chainId != sepoliaChainId) {
        alert("please switch to Ethereum's Sepolia network");
        return;
      }

      //sign the transaction
      const signer = await provider.getSigner();
      const address = await signer.getAddress();
      const sumContract = new ethers.Contract(
        contract_Address,
        contract_ABI,
        signer
      );
      // Setting the global constants
      setSigner(signer);
      setAddress(address);
      setSumContract(sumContract);
      setProvider(provider);
    } else {
      // MetaMask is not installed
      alert("Please install MetaMask extension first!");
    }
  };

  // Handler for calculating sum
  const calculateSum = async () => {
    const num1 = parseInt(number1);
    const num2 = parseInt(number2);
    if (!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) {
      setSum(num1 + num2);
    } else {
      setSum("Invalid input");
    }
    console.log(address);
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
    console.log(balance);
    console.log(sumContract);
    // const canSendTx = balance.gt(1e14);
    if (balance > 1e14)
      return sendTx(sumContract.connect(signer), number1, number2);
    else return sendMetaTx(sumContract, provider, signer, number1, number2);
  };

  async function sendTx(contract, num1, num2) {
    console.log(`Sending num1 to add function, ${num1}`);
    contract.add(num1);
    setNumber1("");
  }

  async function sendMetaTx(contract, provider, signer, num1) {
    console.log(`Sending num1 meta-tx to add function, ${num1}`);
    const url = process.env.REACT_APP_WEBHOOK_URL;
    if (!url) throw new Error(`Missing relayer url`);
    const forwarder = createInstance(provider);
    const from = await signer.getAddress();
    const data = contract.interface.encodeFunctionData("add", [num1]);
    console.log(data);
    const to = contract_Address;
    const request = await signMetaTxRequest(
      signer.provider,
      provider,
      forwarder,
      {
        to,
        from,
        data,
      }
    );

    // axios
    //   .post("${url}", JSON.stringify(request))
    //   .then((response) => {
    //     console.log("Data sent to Relayer:", response.data);
    //     // Reset the form fields
    //     setNumber1("");
    //     setNumber2("");
    //   })
    //   .catch((error) => {
    //     console.error("Error sending data to Relayer:", error);
    //   });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
    const url1 =
      "https://api.defender.openzeppelin.com/actions/fb59a8c1-6e2c-44dc-98a3-555d8889e870/runs/webhook/2a3f8785-400b-49fb-93ae-912b4ae4aa9a/HFp1ZAVAgd6CV9YFRpacnf";
    return fetch(url1, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(request),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Data sent to Relayer:", data);
        // Reset the form fields or do other actions
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending data to Relayer:", error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="title-block" style={{ marginTop: "1em" }}>
        <h1 className="name">Meta Transactions</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="main-menu" style={{ marginTop: "3em" }}>
        <div className="container middle-container">
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="number1">Number 1:</label>
            <input
              id="number1"
              type="number"
              value={number1}
              onChange={(e) => setNumber1(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter number 1"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="number2">Number 2:</label>
            <input
              id="number2"
              type="number"
              value={number2}
              onChange={(e) => setNumber2(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter number 2"
            />
          </div>
          <button onClick={calculateSum}>Sum</button>
          <button onClick={connectWalletHandler}>Connect Wallet</button>
          <div>Result: {sum}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Main;

and finally this is my Actions(Autotask code):
const { Defender } = require("@openzeppelin/defender-sdk");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const { ForwarderAbi } = require("../src/forwarder");
const ForwarderAddress = require("../deploy.json").ERC2771Forwarder;

async function relay(forwarder, request, signature, whitelist) {
  // Decide if we want to relay this request based on a whitelist
  const accepts = !whitelist || whitelist.includes(request.to);
  if (!accepts) throw new Error(`Rejected request to ${request.to}`);

  // Validate request on the forwarder contract
  const valid = await forwarder.verify(request, signature);
  if (!valid) throw new Error(`Invalid request`);

  // Send meta-tx through relayer to the forwarder contract
  const gasLimit = (parseInt(request.gas) + 50000).toString();
  return await forwarder.execute(request, signature, { gasLimit });
}

async function handler(event) {
  // Parse webhook payload
  if (!event.request || !event.request.body) throw new Error(`Missing payload`);
  const { request, signature } = event.request.body;
  console.log(`Relaying`, request);

  // Initialize Relayer provider and signer, and forwarder contract
  const creds = { ...event };
  const client = new Defender(creds);
  const provider = client.relaySigner.getProvider();
  const signer = client.relaySigner.getSigner(provider, { speed: "fast" });
  const forwarder = new ethers.Contract(ForwarderAddress, ForwarderAbi, signer);

  // Relay transaction!
  const tx = await relay(forwarder, request, signature);
  console.log(`Sent meta-tx: ${tx.hash}`);
  return { txHash: tx.hash };
}

module.exports = {
  handler,
  relay,
};


You're passing too many arguments to your smart contract function through the Defender relayer. The error indicates the function expects only one argument.
Solutions:

Check Contract: Verify the add function in MetaSum is defined with just one parameter.

Review main.js: Ensure the function call being relayed (likely involving sumContract.add(...)) includes only the intended
argument (e.g., number1).


This should resolve the error and allow you to interact with your smart contract successfully.
